# How to create a slime bounce cycle?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, animation, eevee-render-engine, meta-objects

How can a get a meta-ball to do this repeatedly, while dropping pieces on every landing?

[image: bouncing slime]

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you have achieved so far ?

Comment: I have got sphere with eyes, but I'm trying to figure out metaballs